# Detect the the vtable offset of a specific virtual function (using Visual C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vtable

Can the vtable offset of a specific virtual function be inspected?

Why? I'd like to be able to detect unintentional binary compatibility breaks (see http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C%2B%2B for what I mean by binary compatibility).

I'm aware of the undocumented and unsupported technique of "/d1reportSingleClassLayout" (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/05/17/diagnosing-hidden-odr-violations-in-visual-c-and-fixing-lnk2022.aspx), and I plan to use this technique, but I'd like to also use some simple compile time or run time checks if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired by Jerry's answer, I managed to write up this function that can do the same thing for any function signature:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    virtual void a() {}
    virtual void b() {}
    virtual void c() {}
};

template <class T>
int SeeBits(T func)
{
    union
    {
        T ptr;
        int i;
    };
    ptr = func;

    return i;
}

int main()
{
    int i = SeeBits(&A::a);
    int j = SeeBits(&A::b);
    int k = SeeBits(&A::c);

    std::cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's ugly, non-portable, crufty, etc., but maybe something on this general order would be useful:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { 
    virtual void a() {}
    virtual void b() {}
    virtual void c() {}
};

int main() { 
    A a;

    typedef void (A::*ptr)();

    union see_bits { 
        ptr p;
        int i;
    };

    see_bits x, y, z;
    x.p = &A::a;
    y.p = &A::b;
    z.p = &A::c;

    std::cout << x.i << "\n";
    std::cout << y.i << "\n";
    std::cout << z.i << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

To be a bit more portable, you should probably use an array of unsigned char as the second element of the union -- printing that out in a meaningful manner will add a bit more work that I'll leave to you (at least for now).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to use those results. The values themselves change between runs (which I suppose is to be expected). But even the differences change. For example, (y.i - x.i) is 155 for some runs and 145 for others (with VC2010). Could you please clarify?

Comment: At least for me, the values change, but the differences are constant. I don't see how the differences could change unless you re-compiled (e.g., with different compiler flags).

Comment: I agree with you, it doesn't make sense, but it seems to happen intermittently when changing unrelated code in the same file, or changing the struct definition and then changing it back.

Why is an array of unsigned char better for the second element?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good example [here](http://kaisar-haque.blogspot.com/2008/07/c-accessing-virtual-table.html). Mind though that you won't be able to retrieve function name, just the address/offset.