# How to write a c++ code according to this reversed code?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I used IDA7 to decompile some binary and got something like this.

Pseudocode:

```
int A::start(){
    int (__fastcall *v3)(B *const); // x2
    unsigned int fd; // w0
    int (__fastcall *v5)(A *const, int); // x3
    int v6; // w20

    v3 = *(this->_vptr.B + 6);    //pointing to getFD (the sixth function of ref_B)
    if ( v3 != B::getFD )
    {
        fd = v3(&this->B);
        v5 = *(this->_vptr.B + 7);
        if ( v5 == B::listen )
            goto LABEL_4;
    LABEL_9:
        v6 = v5(this, fb);
        if ( v6 )
            goto LABEL_10;
        goto LABEL_4;

    }
    fd = this->mFd;
    v5 = *(this->_vptr.B + 7);
    if ( v5 != B::listen )    //major problem here, A doesn't overwrite listen, 
                              //so "v5 != B::listen" never true, 
                              //so we can't just place this->listen(fb) here
        goto LABEL_9;

    LABEL_4:
    if ( evutil_socketpair(1, 1, 0, fd) ) // this one comes from event2
    {
        fd = -1LL;
        return -1;
    }
    LABEL_10:
    return 0;
}
```

And Constructor of A looks like:

Pseudocode:

```
void A::A(A *const this)
{
    B::B(&this->B);
    this->_vptr.B = ref_B;
}
```

ref_B looks like:

```
.data.rel.ro:000000555644D8D8                 DCQ _ZTI1A ; `typeinfo for'A
.data.rel.ro:000000555644D8E0 ref_B           DCQ _ZThn8_N1AD1Ev ; `non-virtual thunk to'A::~A()
.data.rel.ro:000000555644D8E8                 DCQ _ZThn8_N1AD0Ev ; `non-virtual thunk to'A::~A()
.data.rel.ro:000000555644D8F0                 DCQ _ZThn8_N1A4openE8TYPE ; `non-virtual thunk to'A::open(TYPE)
.data.rel.ro:000000555644D8F8                 DCQ _ZThn8_N1A5closeEv ; `non-virtual thunk to'A::close(void)
.data.rel.ro:000000555644D900                 DCQ _ZN1B9get******Ev ; B::get******(void)
.data.rel.ro:000000555644D908                 DCQ _ZN1B9write****EPKcm ; B::write****(char const*,ulong)
.data.rel.ro:000000555644D910                 DCQ _ZN1B5getFDEv ; B::getFD(void)
.data.rel.ro:000000555644D918                 DCQ _ZN1B6listenEi ; `non-virtual thunk to'B::listen(int)
```

struct(class) A looks like:

```
struct __cppobj A : B
{
    pthread_mutex_t mMutex;
};
```

struct(class) B looks like:

```
struct B
{
    int (**_vptr.B)(...);//this is generated by IDA7, and I think
                         // it's pretty much equal to _vptr_B (so dose all '_vptr.B' above)
    int mFd;
};
```

My problem is what kind of source code yields code like A::start. I double checked the assemble code of A::start, and I'm quite sure IDA did the right Pseudocode translation.

I tried to understand the code's behaviour. It looks like A::start wants to judge whether getFD from it's vtable is from ref_B.(if Some class X derive from A and overwrite getFD, but not overwrite start, then calling x.start will calling its getFD instead of using mFd from class B). But I just don't know how to achieve the source code. Will some one so kind to help me out?

Comment: I suspect that this has something to do with thread-safe initialization of vtables, but it's hard to tell, since you've omitted code and we don't know what `Mutex` is. Also, `_vptr.B` is not a valid name for a member, so the output code is ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks too much for answering.. Yes, i've omitted something, which i think not so important. I've updated my question.

Comment: The code that you've provided has a `goto LABEL_4;`, but you've omitted what is found at that label. That information is quite important to answer the question though.

Comment: OK ``. I will initiate another update..

Comment: you might also be interested in [reverseengineering.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code you highlighted is just the compiler optimistically inlining a virtual function with a slow path to fall back to.

The original source code probably is just

```
fd = getFD();
```

where `getFD` is declared in `B` as:

```
virtual int getFD() { return this->mFd; }
```

The compiler cannot know whether `A` in turn is not subclassed with an override for `getFD`, so it must keep the slower virtual call as a backup.

Comment: No.. I've tried this. If i use "fd = getFD();" directly.  There will be no judgement at all. Emm.. I will update my question again, thanks.

Comment: Note that this [speculative devirtualization](https://hubicka.blogspot.com/2014/08/devirtualization-in-c-part-5-asking.html) is based on heuristics, which are influenced by the code around it, the compiler version and compiler flags used

Comment: Yes.. and I've the same feeling, that must be connected with subclassing. But, errrr..can't figure it out for nearly two days. ToT..

Comment: Why does the code have to be _exactly_ the same? The only change in behavior is a tiny bit of speed.

Comment: Yes. But I have to find a way to express those _vptr judgements. Because If there would be a class C derives from A, and overwrite method listen. How should I replicate A::start?? Given I've a ton of code like this to translate, i think the best choise it to translate by "structure", not by meanings. Anyway.. finally got someone to share with.. you have my thanks.

Comment: The code block under `v3 != B::getFD` calls `this->getFD` and the code block under `LABEL_9` calls `this->listen(fd)`. I bet that the implementation of `B::listen` is exactly that call to `evutil_socketpair`. In other words, this entire function can be replaced with `this->listen(this->getFD()))`. To get there, systematically assume that `vX != B::whatever` is true. That will leave you with a simple collection of basic blocks, some of which are never called.

Comment: Thanks again for helping. Saddly, When I debug this code block. "goto LABEL_9;" won't be hit, so this block is equal to "fd = this->mFd;" in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected: the compiler has identified A as a leaf class and is optimistically assuming it is not subclassed. Replacing the method with the virtualized code I put above will ensure your cleaned-up matches the original developer's intent and does not contain inlined methods all over the place.

Comment: Finally, I have the answer. In return for your enthusiastic help, the best answer is yours.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a freakin' answer. It was very twisted, but I decided to put it out there so that it could be taken by a partner in the same situation.

The code that can replace the "

```
v3 = *(this->_vptr.B + 6);
if ( v3 != B::getFD )
{
    fd = v3(&this->B);
    v5 = *(this->_vptr.B + 7);
    if ( v5 == B::listen )
        goto LABEL_4;
LABEL_9:
    v6 = v5(this, fd);
    if ( v6 )
        goto LABEL_10;
    goto LABEL_4;

}
fd = this->mFd;
v5 = *(this->_vptr.B + 7);
if ( v5 != B::listen ) 
    goto LABEL_9;
```

"
part is
"

```
offset = VTableIndex<B>(&B::getFD);
v3 = (int ( *)(B *const)) *((long*)*(long*)((B *)this)+offset);
if ((void*)v3 != (void*)&B::getFD) {
  fb = v3((B *)this);

  offset = VTableIndex<A>(&A::listen);
  v5 = (int ( *)(A *const, int)) *((long*)*(long*)(this)+offset);
  if ( (void*)v5 == (void*)&A::listen )
    goto LABEL_4;
LABEL_9:
  v6 = v5(this, fd);
  if ( v6 )
    goto LABEL_10;
  goto LABEL_4;
}
fb = this->mFd;
offset = VTableIndex<A>(&A::listen);
v5 = (int ( *)(A *const, int)) *((long*)*(long*)(this)+offset);
if ( (void*)v5 != (void*)&A::listen )
  goto LABEL_9;
```

"

, in which I got "VTableIndex" from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635212/detect-the-the-vtable-index-ordinal-of-a-specific-virtual-function-using-visual/5699897#5699897。](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635212/detect-the-the-vtable-index-ordinal-of-a-specific-virtual-function-using-visual/5699897#5699897%E3%80%82)

*Using this substitution, I can mindlessly rewrite the pseudocode directly into C++ source code and easily whore out the results of others.*

Anyway, thanks to the partners who participated in helping me. This is my first time using StackOverflow, so please correct me if there is something wrong.